# Delimiter-separated string to RadTreeView VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, delimiter, radtreeview

I have an array of paths separated by a delimiter:

```
    Dim paths = New List(Of String)() From {
        "C:\WINDOWS\AppPatch\MUI\040C",
        "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727",
        "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\addins\MUI",
        "C:\WINDOWS\addins",
        "C:\WINDOWS\AppPatch",
        "C:\WINDOWS\AppPatch\MUI",
        "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\MUI\MUI\0409"
    }
```

And I want to create a RadTreeView that will look something like this:

```
    +C:
        +Windows
            +AppPatch
            +addins
            +Microsoft.NET
                +Framework
    ...
```

This is what I have managed to do until now but there's something I'm missing:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim paths = New List(Of String)() From {
        "C:\WINDOWS\AppPatch\MUI\040C",
        "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727",
        "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\MUI",
        "C:\WINDOWS\addins",
        "C:\WINDOWS\AppPatch",
        "C:\WINDOWS\AppPatch\MUI",
        "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\MUI\0409"
    }

    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        Dim subPathAgg As String
        Dim pathSeparator As String = "\"

        ' For each complete individual path
        For Each path As String In paths

            subPathAgg = String.Empty

            ' Fill array of strings with each delimited part
            Dim arrFolders As List(Of String) = (path).Split(pathSeparator).ToList
            Dim lastNode As RadTreeNode = Nothing

            Dim iCount As Integer = 0

            'For each one of the folders
            For Each folder As String In path.Split(pathSeparator)
                subPathAgg += folder & pathSeparator

                Dim foundNode As RadTreeNode = RadTreeView1.Nodes.FindNodeByValue(subPathAgg, True)
                If foundNode Is Nothing Then
                    If lastNode Is Nothing Then
                        lastNode = New RadTreeNode(folder, subPathAgg)
                        RadTreeView1.Nodes.Add(lastNode)
                    Else
                        Dim otherNode = New RadTreeNode(folder, subPathAgg)
                        lastNode.Nodes.Add(otherNode)
                        lastNode = otherNode
                    End If
                Else
                    If foundNode.Text <> folder Then
                        Dim otherNode = New RadTreeNode(folder, subPathAgg)
                        foundNode.Nodes.Add(otherNode)
                        lastNode = otherNode
                    End If
                End If

            Next
            lastNode = Nothing

        Next

    End If

End Sub
```

[This is how the TreeView looks like right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yN0ai.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the solution on the Telerik forums:

C#

```
private void AddNode(RadTreeView treeView, string path)
 {
     List<string> folders = GetPaths(path);
     folders.Reverse();
     for (int i = 0; i < folders.Count; i++)
     {
     RadTreeNode node = treeView.FindNodeByValue(folders[i]);
     string folderName = GetCurrentFolder(folders[i]);
     if (node == null)
     {
         if (i == 0)
         {
         treeView.Nodes.Add(new RadTreeNode(folderName, folders[i]));
         }
         else
         {
         treeView.FindNodeByValue(folders[i - 1]).Nodes.Add(new RadTreeNode(folderName, folders[i]));
         }
     }
     else
     {
         if (node.Text != folderName)
         {
         node.Nodes.Add(new RadTreeNode(folderName, folders[i]));
         }
     }
     }
 }

 private string GetCurrentFolder(string path)
 {
     var folders = path.Split(new string[] { "\\" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
     return folders[folders.Count() - 1];
 }

 private List<string> GetPaths(string path)
 {
     List<string> paths = new List<string>();
     paths.Add(path);
     while (path.LastIndexOf("\\") >= 0)
     {
     path = path.Substring(0, path.LastIndexOf("\\"));
     paths.Add(path);
     };       
     return paths;
 }

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
 {

     dynamic paths = new List<string> {
     "C:\\WINDOWS\\AppPatch\\MUI\\040C",
     "C:\\WINDOWS\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727",
     "C:\\WINDOWS\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727\\MUI",
     "C:\\WINDOWS\\addins",
     "C:\\WINDOWS\\AppPatch",
     "C:\\WINDOWS\\AppPatch\\MUI",
     "C:\\WINDOWS\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727\\MUI\\0409"
 };

     if (!Page.IsPostBack)
     {
     foreach (string path in paths)
     {
         AddNode(RadTreeView1, path);
     }
     }
 }
```

VB.NET:

```
Private Sub AddNode(treeView As RadTreeView, path As String)
    Dim folders As List(Of String) = GetPaths(path)
    folders.Reverse()
    For i As Integer = 0 To folders.Count - 1
    Dim node As RadTreeNode = treeView.FindNodeByValue(folders(i))
    Dim folderName As String = GetCurrentFolder(folders(i))
    If node Is Nothing Then
        If i = 0 Then
        treeView.Nodes.Add(New RadTreeNode(folderName, folders(i)))
        Else
        treeView.FindNodeByValue(folders(i - 1)).Nodes.Add(New RadTreeNode(folderName, folders(i)))
        End If
    Else
        If node.Text <> folderName Then
        node.Nodes.Add(New RadTreeNode(folderName, folders(i)))
        End If
    End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Function GetCurrentFolder(path As String) As String
    Dim folders = path.Split(New String() {"\"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
    Return folders(folders.Count() - 1)
End Function

Private Function GetPaths(path As String) As List(Of String)
    Dim paths As New List(Of String)()
    paths.Add(path)
    While path.LastIndexOf("\") >= 0
    path = path.Substring(0, path.LastIndexOf("\"))
    paths.Add(path)
    End While


    Return paths
End Function

Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)

    Dim paths As dynamic = New List(Of String)() From { _
    "C:\WINDOWS\AppPatch\MUI\040C", _
    "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727", _
    "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\MUI", _
    "C:\WINDOWS\addins", _
    "C:\WINDOWS\AppPatch", _
    "C:\WINDOWS\AppPatch\MUI", _
    "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\MUI\0409" _
    }

    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
    For Each path As String In paths
        AddNode(RadTreeView1, path)
    Next
    End If
End Sub
```